# Lie algebra cohomology: Künneth formula for semidirect product?

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

In trying to understand an example of Lie algebra for which every one-dimensional extension splits (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/443786/147463)), but not every extension splits, I found it necessary to use the following isomorphism: If $\mathfrak s$ is a semisimple Lie algebra over a field $k$ and $V$ is any $\mathfrak s$-module, then $$H^2(\mathfrak s\ltimes V,k)\cong \Bigl(\textstyle\bigwedge^{2}V^*\Bigr)^\mathfrak{s}$$ I thought this was a nice fact and wondered if it perhaps reflected a broader phenomenon. Through successive (and slow) attempts to realize this formula as a shadow of something more general, I came upon a guess as to a Künneth-like formula: If $\mathfrak g$ acts on $\mathfrak h$ by derivations, then
$$H^n(\mathfrak g\ltimes \mathfrak h,k)=\bigoplus_{i+j=n}H^i\bigl(\mathfrak g,H^j(\mathfrak h,k)\bigr).$$
Taking $\mathfrak g$ to be semisimple and $\mathfrak h$ to be abelian, this does indeed give back $$H^2(\mathfrak{s}\ltimes V,k)=\textstyle H^2(\mathfrak{s},k)\oplus H^1(\mathfrak{s},V^{*})\oplus H^0\big(\mathfrak s,\bigwedge^2V^{*}\big)=\big(\bigwedge^2V^{*}\big)^\mathfrak{s}.$$
If the $\mathfrak g$-action on $\mathfrak h$ is trivial, so that we have a direct product $\mathfrak g\times \mathfrak h$, then this Künneth formula for a semidirect product would be equivalent to the more typical formula for a direct product.

My question, for someone who knows more about Lie algebras than myself, consists of three parts:

1. Is this formula true? If so, can you point me to somewhere in the literature where this statement or something similar is discussed?
2. If this formula is not true, are there some reasonable modifications that will give a similar, factual statement?
3. This is a tangentially related bonus question, but is there any sort of universal coefficients theorem for Lie algebra cohomology, which can relate $H^{*}(\mathfrak g,V)$ and $H^{*}(\mathfrak g,k)$?

Comment: In general, there is a Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence
$$E_2^{p,q} = H^p\big(\mathfrak g,H^q(\mathfrak h,k)\big) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}\big(\mathfrak h \rtimes \mathfrak g,k\big);$$
see for instance §7.5 in Weibel's *An introduction to homological algebra*. But unlike the Künneth formula, the spectral sequence for semidirect products has no reason to degenerate (as far as I can tell), so it will probably be more complicated than the direct sum. (At least for finite groups, you don't get something as simple as this, but maybe Lie algebras are somehow better!)

Comment: I am far from an expert on Lie algebras, so I don't really have more detailed references or thoughts about whether this spectral sequence degenerates in certain cases. I hope someone more knowledgeable than myself can add some more details.

Comment: If you're in characteristic zero, finite dimensional modules for a semisimple Lie algebra don't extend each other, and your spectral sequence should collapse at $E_2$. However, this is not at all the case in characteristic $p$.  I'm also more familiar with the group situation, where the LHS spectral sequence of a semidirect product definitely doesn't collapse at $E_2$, even if the kernel is abelian. I wrote a paper with Mark Feshbach, back when he was still around (Proc AMS 121, 1994) on the subject, and Burt Totaro wrote a very nice paper giving conceptual reasons for this (J Alg 182, 1996).

Comment: @LSpice I did mean to link my answer, since that's where I used the isomorphism inspiring this question, but I realize that's probably more confusing than helpful, so I changed the link to go the question.

Comment: @DaveBenson and R.vanDobbendeBruyn: Thank you, this is really useful perspective! My knowledge of spectral sequences is very shaky, so I could see that one would probably come up, but I didn't know what it might be called or how to investigate the possibility of degeneration. The Weibel reference is useful in showing that if I were considering a non-split sequence, degeneration would be way to good to hope for! But if this should be true for a split extension, I might try to write down a proof for myself that circumvents the spectral sequences…

Comment: @DaveBenson's [references](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444675/lie-algebra-cohomology-k%c3%bcnneth-formula-for-semidirect-product#comment1148165_444675): [Benson and Feshbach - On the cohomology of split extensions](https://doi.org/10.2307/2160262); [Totaro - Cohomology of semidirect product groups](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1996.0181).

Comment: The direct sum decomposition you want exists as long as the complex computing $H^* ( \mathfrak h, k)$ is isomorphic in the derived category to a direct sum of its cohomology objects.

This happens if $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple (since every complex of $\mathfrak g$-representations is then isomorphic in the derived category to a direct sum of its cohomology objects - basically Dave Benson's argument) *or* $\mathfrak h$ is abelian (since viewed as a representation of $GL_n$ we can apply the previous argument and then restrict to $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ and then to $\mathfrak g$).

Comment: I don't see any reason the semidirectness should force a splitting if $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ are both horrible complicated nilpotent Lie algebras though.

Comment: @WillSawin The Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence applies to an extension, which in this case is $$\mathfrak h\hookrightarrow \mathfrak g\ltimes \mathfrak h\rightarrow \mathfrak g.$$ Because $\mathfrak g$ is a subalgebra complementary to $\mathfrak h$, it defines a splitting. I was under the impression that an extension $$\mathfrak h\hookrightarrow \mathfrak e\rightarrow \mathfrak g$$ splits if and only if $\mathfrak e\cong \mathfrak g\ltimes \mathfrak h$ for some action of $\mathfrak g$ by derivations on $\mathfrak h$.

Comment: If $s$ is an arbitrary Lie algebra and $V$ an $s$-module, then the semidirect product $s\ltimes V$ can be graded with $s$ of degree 0 and $V$ of degree 1. This induces a grading of the exterior powers and hence of the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex, and hence of the (co)homology. This is convenient to treat such a question degree-wise. The degree 0 part will obviously be the (co)homology of $s$. For $H_n$ each degree up to $n$ has to be considered and for $n=2$ you probably obtained the degree 0, 1, 2 parts.

Comment: @NikhilSahoo Sorry, I meant "force a degeneration" and not "force a splitting". I don't see why the splitting forces a degeneration.

Comment: @YCor I think your grading gives the desired direct sum statement since it forces the differentials to vanish (otherwise they wouldn't respect the grading) and then forces the filtration arising from the exact sequence to be a direct sum (I guess showing that it's a direct sum of representations of any group acting on the whole setup and respecting the semidirect product structure). This argument seems a bit more elegant than the one in my comment https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444675/lie-algebra-cohomology-k%c3%bcnneth-formula-for-semidirect-product?noredirect=1#comment1148176_444675

Comment: @WillSawin yes for the group statement: this is just because (co)homology of Lie algebras graded in a given abelian group is functorial with respect to degree-preserving Lie algebra homomorphisms.